# Excel: Search for keywords within a matrix to build a relation in another

Tags: excel, search, matrix, vlookup

First of all, thanks for all who read through - It's not easy to explain it with words, as iam not allowed to post pictures yet.

**Here we go:**
Imagine 2 sheets within an excel document.

**Sheet1: The Matrix**
In Column A you'll find a 'description text' for a specific problem
Column B (and the following) are filled with several information to the problem, but we don't need them for my current problem.

**Sheet2: Relation**
I've got another table with Error-Description and IDs. Unfortunetaly those who write the description text don't use the same sentences as I do for my error-description. But i need to get a relation, to further analyze the problem.

**To do so**, i created another sheet with 'keywords' and the ID of the error. 
Trying several things iam not able to....: (Now the problem starts for all tldr;)

**HOW do I build up the relation**. Keywords are set as

*"*test*" "*what*error*customer*"* and so on.

While the description text is more like

*"We had a test here but it failed"* and so on..

**I want** to add a column in the first sheet (sheet1: Matrix) with the ID.
So I need to search within the description text for the keywords and return the ID.

Any idea how I could do this?

Edit:
Here an picture (just got my rep. points) :

[image]

I want the Text beeing related to the ID by looking for the keywords.
Iam very thankful for ANY help

Comment: Guys... for real. Downvoting this don't help me out. If there's something unclear, feel free to ask, so i may describe it more clearly.

Comment: I've read the question a couple of times, and even with the pictures, I have no idea what you're askng

Comment: Even with the picture? Okay, let my try to explain even closer. In the relation-sheet you see keywords with an ID. In Sheet 1 you see a free-text. I want the ID (which can be more than one, as you see, i seperated it with comas, but this doesnt matter at all: i want the value of the related B-column) to be filled within Sheet1. If it i.e. finds a \*tldr\* (where * is for free character(s)) like it does in Sheet1!A3 it should fill Sheet1!B3 with the related ID => Relation!B3... Still unclear? @LittleBobbyTables

Answer (score 0):

For those who face the same problem, got it solved.

```
=lookup(2;1/SEARCH(Relation!A$2:A$5;Sheet1!A2);Relation!B:B)
```